# Python Elasticsearch timed out, curl works fine between docker containers

Tags: python, elasticsearch, docker

I have two docker containers both using the docker bridge network.

One container has Elasticsearch 2.6.1 running. The other has an ubuntu image running with some python code.

Whatever the elasticsearch query I want to execute, it works perfectly using Curl from the ubuntu container shell.

When I try to do the same in the ubuntu container using Python-Elasticsearch library, I get a timed out error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test_elastics.py", line 11, in <module>
      res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
      return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 279, in index
      _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 329, in perform_request
      status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 102, in perform_request
raise ConnectionTimeout('TIMEOUT', str(e), e)
      elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host=u'172.17.0.1', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=30))
```

I'm using docker 1.7.1 on a RHEL distribution.

The same containers on my macbook running the latest Docker CE 17.06 run flawlessly.

I don't understand what is happening, if Curl is able to reach elasticsearch why not urllib?

Thank you for your help.

PS: One strange thing is that it seems that the python script is able to create the indexes...

**UPDATE 1**

The docker image that I use for the elasticsearch container is this one https://github.com/partlab/docker/tree/master/ubuntu-elasticsearch

I add this two lines to elasticsearch.yml :

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

and I run the container using this command line:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 --name cca_elasticsearch -v /home/myhome/elastic_data dc6da47c125a
```

**UPDATE 2**

The curl requests that I tried:

```
foo@b8b74b6e5609:~$ curl 172.17.0.1:9200
{
  "name" : "Puff Adder",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "s58rhxIuRKqUjEJF-ckOIQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.6",
    "build_hash" : "5376dca9f70f3abef96a77f4bb22720ace8240fd",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-07-18T12:17:44Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

An other one to check the indexes:

```
foo@b8b74b6e5609:~$ curl '172.17.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index      pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
```

And I tried this new one which failed, sorry I wasn't thorough in my tests:

```
foo@b8b74b6e5609:~$ curl -XPUT '172.17.0.1:9200/megacorp/employee/1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "first_name" : "John", "last_name" : "Smith", "age" : 25, "about" : "I love to go rock climbing", "interests": [ "sports", "music" ] } '
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "unavailable_shards_exception",
      "reason" : "[megacorp][3] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [index {[megacorp][employee][1], source[ { \"fir
st_name\" : \"John\", \"last_name\" : \"Smith\", \"age\" : 25, \"about\" : \"I love to go rock climbing\", \"interests\": [ \"sports
\", \"music\" ] } ]}]"
    } ],
    "type" : "unavailable_shards_exception",
    "reason" : "[megacorp][3] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [index {[megacorp][employee][1], source[ { \"first
_name\" : \"John\", \"last_name\" : \"Smith\", \"age\" : 25, \"about\" : \"I love to go rock climbing\", \"interests\": [ \"sports\"
, \"music\" ] } ]}]"
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

This seems like the same problem than with my Python code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch('172.17.0.1:9200')

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['created'])
```

**UPDATE 3**

Something wrong is happening with my elasticsearch docker and I just noticed it.

Here are the tail of the docker logs for that container:

https://paste.atilla.org/paste/XE95RD/raw

Comment: Are you doing container linking or some other method to make elasticsearch accessible to the application container?

Comment: @jordanm I'm fairly new to docker so i'm not really familiar with container linking, what I do is make sure that both my containers are on the docker bridge network and I use the IP given to my elasticsearch container to reach it from the ubuntu container.

Comment: Using `docker network connect`?

Comment: docker network management is not available in docker 1.7.1 so i'm not using it (but on my macbook yes I use it), I just run using the --net="bridge" flag.

Comment: Can you update the question to show exactly the curl command you're using, as well as the python code where you set up the request (instantiating `Elasticsearch`, plus the actual query)?

Comment: @dshockley done

Comment: @mandok you said in the python script, you successfully created the index, right? Is it possible the index wasn't "ready" yet when it received the index request? (To test this you can probably just put a `sleep(30)` in between the requests.) I think that you should get a response, not a timeout in that case, but it's something to try. Also can you show the python code creating the index?

Comment: Other question, is there a reason you have to use an old version of ES instead of 5.5?

Comment: @mandok with that version of docker, you need to use legacy linking or `--net=host`

Comment: @dshockley The code that creates the index is the one that you can find in the update 2, I tried that same code with a time out parameters of 30s and same issue, but as you can see in update 3 my elasticsearch is failing which never happened on my mac and it's the same image.
I'm using ES 2.6.1 because it's a requirement of my project, no choice about that and I don't know the exact reasons.

Comment: @jordanm ok, i'm going to try using `--net=host` even if looking at my docker logs in update 3 the issue seems to come from that container

Comment: Those logs are very helpful -- it says `No space left on device`. I haven't seen that before on Linux (except in case there was actually no space left/no inodes free), but I haven't used redhat. Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203168/docker-says-no-space-left-on-device-but-system-has-plenty-of-space) is relevant?